# Use closures in Yii2 ArrayDataProvider

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

In an **ActiveDataProvider** you can use closures as values, like:

```
$dataprovider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $array
]);

$gridColumns = [
    'attrib_1',
    [
        'attribute' => 'attrib_2',
        'label' => 'Label_2',
        'value' => function($model) {
            return Html::encode($model->value_2);
        }
    ],
    'attrib_3'
];

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataprovider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
]);
```

Is it possible to do the same or something like this, in an **ArrayDataProvider**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Only difference is that $model is not an object but array so:

```
'value' => function($model) {
    return Html::encode($model['value_2']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought, there is no model, because the dataprovider is based on an self created array.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, I have created an extended version of ActiveDataProvider, that for each model got from provider I call a callback.

1. This is the custom ActiveDataProvider, put in common\components namespace in this case.

   ```
   <?php

   namespace common\components;

   class CustomActiveDataProvider extends \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider
   {
   public $formatModelOutput = null;

   public function getModels()
   {
       $inputModels = parent::getModels();
       $outputModels = [];

       if($this->formatModelOutput != null)
       {
           for($k=0;$k<count($inputModels);$k++)
           {
               $outputModels[] = call_user_func( $this->formatModelOutput, $k , $inputModels[$k]); 
           }
       }
       else
       {
           $outputModels = $inputModels;           
       }


       return $outputModels;
   }
   }
   ```
2. This is the action in controller that uses it. For reusability, I call a model method instead calling a clousure, but you can call also a clousure.

   ```
    public function actionIndex()
    {
         $query = Model::find();

    $dataProvider = new \common\components\CustomActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => ['pageSize' => null],
        'formatModelOutput' => function($id, $model) {
            return $model->dataModelPerActiveProvider;
        }
    ]);

   return $dataProvider;
   }
   ```
3. At last, this is the method getDataModelPerActiveProvider in model:

   ```
   public function getDataModelPerActiveProvider()
   {
        $this->id = 1;
        // here you can customize other fields
        // OR you can also return a custom array, for example:
        // return ['field1' => 'test', 'field2' => 'foo', 'field3' => $this->id];
        return $this;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this too!